# How to set current date as default date in mySQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sql-server, date

I have a table `Members` with column `DayJoin` of type `varchar`. I want to set default value of the column `DayJoin` should be the current day if user does not enter a value for that field.

In MSSQL Server I wrote this statement:

```
CREATE TABLE Members
(
ID int identity (1,1) primary key,
Email varchar(50),
Password Varchar(50),
Role Varchar(50) default 'Member',
DayJoin varchar(50) DEFAULT Convert(varchar, GETDATE(),103),
LastLogin varchar(50)DEFAULT Convert(varchar, GETDATE(),103),
FName varchar(50),
LName varchar(50),
Phone varchar(50),
DOB varchar(50),
Gender varchar(50),
IDcard varchar(50),
Address varchar(50),
City varchar(50),
Job varchar(50),
Avatar varchar(50) default 'images/noavatar.gif'
)
```

The statement gets the value of the current day and formats it as (dd/mm/yyyy). But when I run a similar one in mySQL, it's not working

```
CREATE TABLE `NewTable` (
`ID`  int UNSIGNED NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
`Email`  varchar(50) NULL ,
`Password`  varchar(50) NULL DEFAULT '' ,
`Role`  varchar(10) NULL ,
`DayJoin`  varchar(10) NULL DEFAULT 'CURRENT_TIMESTAMP' ,
`LastLogin`  varchar(10) NULL DEFAULT 'date_format(now(),%Y/%m/%d)' ,
`Firstname`  varchar(50) NULL ,
`Lastname`  varchar(50) NULL ,
`Phone`  varchar(20) NULL ,
`DOB`  varchar(10) NULL ,
`Gender`  varchar(20) NULL ,
`IDcard`  varchar(20) NULL ,
`Address`  varchar(50) NULL ,
`City`  varchar(50) NULL ,
`Job`  varchar(50) NULL ,
`Avatar`  varchar(50) NULL DEFAULT 'images/noavatar.gif' ,
PRIMARY KEY (`ID`)
)
ENGINE=ARCHIVE
DEFAULT CHARACTER SET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci
;
```

I get a response saying something like; "default value in error"

Does anyone know what the problem is?

Comment: try: `DayJoin  TIMESTAMP NULL DEFAULT 'CURRENT_TIMESTAMP'` ,

Comment: can you share the error message?

Comment: This is my error. I used Navicat to connect to the database.

Sorry I do not have enough something to post Image. You can view by link http://i.upanh.com/viafev

Ques 1: I have tried date. datetime, TIMESTAMP...but It isn't work. I show the same error...

Ques 2: I want to format it into dd/mm/yy in stead yyyy/mm/dd and using the slashback (/) not (-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

remove the quotes around 'CURRENT_TIMESTAMP' in your code and use TIMESTAMP data type. It should read like:

```
`DayJoin`  TIMESTAMP NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
```

Comment: I can't remove, I use Navicat to solve the SQL Query. CURRENT_TIMESTAMP just works only with timestamp. I have used datetime but it's not successfull...

Answer (score 1):

Use `DATETIME` type instead:

```
`DayJoin` DATETIME DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
```

Comment: This is my error. I used Navicat to connect to the database.

Sorry I do not have enough something to post Image. You can view by link http://i.upanh.com/viafev

Ques 1: I have tried date. datetime, TIMESTAMP...but It isn't work. I show the same error...

Ques 2: I want to format it into dd/mm/yy in stead yyyy/mm/dd and using the slashback (/) not (-)

Answer (score 1):

It will give error as "Invalid default value for 'DayJoin' "

Use datetime or timestamp datatype for 'DayJoin'

```
`DayJoin`  TimeStamp NULL DEFAULT 'CURRENT_TIMESTAMP' ,
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this change your `DayJoin` datatype

```
`DayJoin` TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
```

or

```
`DayJoin`  TimeStamp NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
```

Comment: I had successfull with `DayJoin` TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP.
But It allowed only one column use TIMESTAMP. How can I do with the column Lastlogin as same default values.

And how can I format it. I đon't want take the hour, minute and second in that.

Comment: Notthing, It works...but I want to remove the time in it, I mean that I want to take only day month year, I don't want to take hour minutes and second in it. What can I do guy ?

Comment: you can use Date as datatype @user3349931

Comment: I have tried. If use (date) the (CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) as default will not work. The error is the same above.

Comment: I have used date_format(now(),"%Y-%m-%d") to make default of a Column type date. I try to exec query "Select date_format(now(),"%Y-%m-%d");" on mysql and it works. But as the default it says false.

Comment: @TommyDo first you gave my answer as accepted and next day you gave it to someone..That's why i asked you

Comment: Sorry, I didn't understand your mention. I apologize that if I made mistakes and made you misunderstand me !